# Display javascript quiz after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, web

I would like to display this quiz after a button is clicked (onclick). At this moment it appears directly into the website. I am sure is pretty simple but I am stuck here. Do you know how should I add the button code?

Here the HTML:

```
  <div id="quiz"></div>
```

Here the JavaScript quiz:

```
(function() {
function buildQuiz() {
  const output = [];

  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    const answers = [];

    for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
      answers.push(
        `<label>
        <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
        ${letter} :
        ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
      </label>`
      );
    }

    output.push(
      `<div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>`
    );
  });

  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
}


const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the best site ever created?",
    answers: {
      a: "SitePoint",
      b: "Simple Steps Code",
      c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  }
];
```

Comment: Add an onclick event to your button, then have that execute the code above.

Comment: <button onclick="buildQuiz()">Click me</button>
This is not working :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to get what you want accomplished. Here is what I think is the best way.

1. Make buildQuiz a 1st order function by taking it out of the nameless function call. This will give other functions the ability to call on it.
2. Create an event listener that houses all the javascript you want to utilyze that runs after the DOM content is loaded. That looks like this:

   `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
      //code to be run after DOM is ready
   }`

This will allow your code to run only when the DOM is ready and allow you to organize how your code is run.

3. Place an event listener for the button that you want to control the creation of you quiz within the previously mentioned event listener. Within this callback will be the call to create your quiz.

Heres a [codepen](https://codepen.io/osa10928/pen/mMRPVK) that illustrates how this would work. Also in your real thing it would be important to includes a noscript tag incase the person doesn't have javascript enabled on their browser. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I added a button and even listener for click on button. I think this helps

```js
(function() {
function buildQuiz() {
  
  document.getElementById("showQuiz").style.visibility = "hidden"
  const output = [];

  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    const answers = [];

    for (letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
      answers.push(
        `<label>
        <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
        ${letter} :
        ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
      </label>`
      );
    }

    output.push(
      `<div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
    <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>`
    );
  });

  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
}


var quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
var myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the best site ever created?",
    answers: {
      a: "SitePoint",
      b: "Simple Steps Code",
      c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  }
];
  document.getElementById('showQuiz').addEventListener('click',buildQuiz);
}());
```

```html
<button id="showQuiz">Show Quiz</button>
<div id="quiz"></div>
```